# Dynamic Workflow Association to Newly Provisioned SharePoint Online Sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

We have an ongoing technical challenge with my current project, we need an automated mechanism that can automatically associate Power Automate workflows with newly provisioned SharePoint sites.

However, we expect to have a total of 25 to 30 medium and highly complex workflows within a single site collection, and the configuration of all 25-30 workflow typically takes a lot of time. Here is one simple use case.

**Example**: When a user initiates a site provisioning request in the Hub site, an automated process generates a new SharePoint site, which includes a 'Task' list and until here we have achieved it. The primary challenge lies in associating a Power Automate workflow with a Task list, with the workflow's function being to send an email when a task is assigned. Our goal is to discover a solution that simplifies this procedure, eliminating the need for manual configuration, specifically concerning the site URL and task list name within the workflow trigger point.

Here is a visual representation of the problem statement (Dynamic Flow representation):

[image]